# Python 3: Multiple mails being sent using a 'for loop' instead of single mail

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below script which is perfectly working, but when I read the status of the Cisco devices using a for loop and send mail using the user defined function send_mail(), I am receiving two mails instead of one mail, any suggestions to get a single mail, will be greatly appreciated:

```
username = 'cisco'
password = 'cisco'
hosts = ['10.0.10.100','10.0.10.101']
platform = 'cisco_ios'

def send_mail():
    fromaddr = "@gmail.com"
    toaddr = "@hotmail.com"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = '@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = '@hotmail.com'
    msg['Subject'] = "This is Health check"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(status, 'plain'))   
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "password")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()

for host in hosts:
    #print(host)
    connect = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password)
    output = connect.send_command('terminal length 0', expect_string=r'#')
    output = connect.send_command('enable',expect_string=r'#')
    host_name = connect.send_command('show run | in hostname',expect_string=r'#')
    interface_status = connect.send_command(f'show ip int brief',expect_string=r'#')
    #print(interface_status)
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    interface_result = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = interface_result
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    data = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(interface_status),  widths=[27, 16, 3, 7, 23, 8])

    status = " "
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if row[4] == 'administratively down' or row[4] == 'down':
            log = (f"\nInterface {row[0]} is down in {host_name}\n")
            status += log


    bgp_status = connect.send_command('show ip bgp summary | be N',expect_string=r'#')
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    bgp_result = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = bgp_result
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    bgp_data = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(bgp_status),  delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    for index, row in bgp_data.iterrows():
        if row[9] == 'Down' or row[9] == 'Idle' or row[9] == 'Active':
            bgp = (f"\nNeighbor {row[0]} is down in {host_name}\n")
            status += bgp
    send_mail()
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is iterating over two items, and sending an email each time. Why are you only expecting a single email to be sent?

Comment: This script is for a daily health check of devices, single mail should be sent as per management requirement, I have tried to send the mail from outside of the for loop, but I am getting only one mail for the first device, the output from second device is skipped totally

Comment: Ok, but you are calling `send_mail()` within each `for` loop. And then looping through this twice. Why are you expecting to only receive one email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what your issue is. In short, you are calling `send_mail()` within each `for` loop, whereas you actually want to collect statuses for each host, and then send a final status report as one email. This is a short example to illustrate how you might do this - obviously you will have to adapt your code accordingly.

A couple of points:

- Rather than having `send_mail` rely on a global `status` variable, pass in a `status` argument. This helps decouple functions from each other.
- You might want to collect statuses for each host in a list, and then combine them in a logical manner when sending your status email.
- String concatenation is slow. Better to build a list of strings, and join them using the string `join` function.

Here is some example code:

```
hosts = ['10.0.10.100','10.0.10.101']

def send_mail(status=''):
    '''A placeholder function for testing'''
    print("Sending email:\n{status}".format(status=status))
    return

status_for_hosts = []

for host in hosts:
    status_list = []
    # An example of how you might collect statuses for a host
    status_list.append("Host {host_ip} is up".format(host_ip=host))
    # Use join() instead of string concatenation
    full_status = ''.join(status_list)
    status_for_hosts.append(full_status)

send_mail(status='\n'.join(status_for_hosts))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help